# Updating XML data stored in Snowflake in a variant column

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where in I need to update XML data stored in a Snowflake table. Can we update an XML document/element stored in a table with column data type as Variant

In the following example, need to update the value "4"  to a new value of 400.

```
create or replace table xml_demo (id integer, object_col object);
insert into xml_demo (id, object_col)
    select 1001,
        parse_xml('<level1> 1X <level2> 2Y <level3> 3X </level3> <level3> 4 </level3> </level2> </level1>');
select object_col,
       xmlget(object_col, 'level2'),
       xmlget(xmlget(object_col, 'level2'), 'level3', 1)
    from xml_demo;
```

Comment: While in principle it's possible to update a nested XML node, it would require un-nesting and storing the node hierarchy containing it, deleting and reconstructing. A much better option would be a Java UDF to modify the XML using an XML DOM library, and updating the whole column with the results of the UDF.  I have not seen anyone write a Java UDF to do this, but it would not be too hard for people who know Java and how to compile a JAR file with dependent libraries. Another option is an external function. You could also process externally and update from the external processing

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will try with an external function.

Comment: IMO it is not good practice to keep data in semi-structured format once you want to process/use it. Load it as semi-structured, decide how you want to use it, and the convert it to tables in relational format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left too many specifics unspecified, but let's do this.

First we need to specify a way to navigate to the value "4" you want to update. In this XML object, a way to specify this position is `['$',1,'$',2,'$']`. This as we navigate the object, we get to the second element (level2), and then to the 3rd element (level3, with the value 4). With 1->2nd, and 2->3rd, in a 0 based array.

We are going to create a JS UDF that gets a XML object in Snowflake, navigates it in said way, and updates the value in that place:

```sql
create or replace function stacko_update_xml(X object, A array, NEW_VALUE float)
returns object
language javascript
as $$
var element = X;
// traverse tree to element
for (var i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
  element = element[A[i]]
}
element['$'] = NEW_VALUE;
return X;
$$
;
```

Then to `UPDATE` the object with the `id=1001`:

```sql
update xml_demo
set object_col = stacko_update_xml(object_col, ['$',1,'$',2,'$'], 400)
where id = 1001;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Felipe, i will use the function and work on it.